# Update row in sqlite table

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I'm new to xcode and I'm trying to update an sqlite table, if a row already exists. When I run this code, it builds but does not execute the updateAlumni query. It logs "update!" though.

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    IF (sqlite3_prepare(alumniDB, update_stmt, -1, &stmt, nil)== SQLITE_OK) {
        IF (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        NSLog(@"update!");
        const CHAR *updateAlumni = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE ALUMNI SET EMAIL = ?, PHONE = ?, ADDRESS = ?, BIRTHDAY = ? WHERE FIRSTNAME = '%s' AND LASTNAME = '%s'", [ContactFirstName UTF8String], [ContactLastName UTF8String]] UTF8String];

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [ContactEmail UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [ContactPhone UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [ContactAddress UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [ContactBday UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        IF(sqlite3_exec(alumniDB, updateAlumni, NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Alumni updated");
        }
    }
    ELSE{
        NSLog(@"add!");
        NSString *ADD = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ALUMNI(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,PHONE,ADDRESS,BIRTHDAY) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",[ContactFirstName UTF8String],[ContactLastName UTF8String],[ContactEmail UTF8String],[ContactPhone UTF8String],[ContactAddress UTF8String],[ContactBday UTF8String]];
        const CHAR *addAlumni = [ADD UTF8String];

        IF(sqlite3_exec(alumniDB, addAlumni, NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Alumni added");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When debugging try updating one thing first, to make sure that you can atleast modify some part and to ensure your previous code all works. Once that update is successful attempt again with the next set of variables, this way you can possibly find the solution to your problem by breaking it down into little steps first

Comment: Capture and log your the sqlite3_exec return codes.  (And the step and prepare return codes.)  And run tests of your statements with the `sqlite3` command line tool.

Comment: I'm new to this `IF/ELSE` statement in Objective-C. Perhaps you misspelled "if/else"?

Comment: hi Pavan, I tried doing what you suggested. It's updating, but just for the first row. The updateAlumni doesn't execute for the following rows. Do you know how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You are using `stmt` for the wrong statement. And `sqlite3_exec` does not work with parameters. Read the documentation!